# std containers leaking memory on dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, memory-leaks, stdvector

I load a dll with win32 LoadLibrary, and when I am done with it, I call FreeLibrary, destorying all the memory allocated in the dll ect... Actually, memory leak problem only occures with std containers. It seems they are not willing to release their memory on destroy. Here is the code that leaks.

```
namespace ToolKit
{

  class Game : public GamePlugin
  {
  public:
    void Init(ToolKit::Main* master);
    void Destroy();
    void Frame(float deltaTime, Viewport* viewport);
    void Resize(int width, int height);
    void Event(SDL_Event event);

    std::vector<int> point; // If I remove this line, no leaks are reported.
  };

}

extern "C" TK_GAME_API ToolKit::Game * __stdcall GetInstance()
{
  return new ToolKit::Game(); // Instance is deleted in the caller process than FreeLibrary() is called.
}
```

All functions are no-op in GamePlugin, and the process is not reporting any memory issue if there is no std container. I trap the leak in here. For the completion, I am sharing my standart CRT memory dump code.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);    
  return ToolKit_Main(argc, argv);
}
```

Load and unload code for the dll

```
  void PluginManager::Load(const String& name)
  {
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    TKPROC ProcAdd;
    BOOL fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;

    String dllName = name;
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(dllName.c_str());

    if (hinstLib != NULL)
    {
      m_moduleHandle = (void*)hinstLib;
      ProcAdd = (TKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "GetInstance");

      if (NULL != ProcAdd)
      {
        fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
        m_plugin = (ProcAdd)();
        m_plugin->Init(ToolKit::Main::GetInstance());
      }
    }

    if (!fRunTimeLinkSuccess)
    {
      m_reporterFn("Can not load plugin module " + dllName);
    }
  }

  void PluginManager::Unload()
  {
    if (m_plugin)
    {
      m_plugin->Destroy();
      SafeDel(m_plugin);
    }

    if (m_moduleHandle)
    {
      FreeLibrary((HINSTANCE)m_moduleHandle);
      m_moduleHandle = nullptr;
    }
  }
```

Inorder to add some more clarification to the question, I am describing the program flow here:

1. PluginManager::Load loads the dll
2. GetInstance function is fetched from the dll
3. GetInstance return a plugin instance and it is stored in m_plugin
4. PluginManager::Unload deletes m_plugin and free the dll.

Here is the minimalcase that reproduces the leak.
Process side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Plugin.h"

using namespace std;

class PluginManager
{
public:
  void Load(const string& plugin);
  void Unload();

public:
  GamePlugin* m_plugin = nullptr;
  void* m_moduleHandle = nullptr;
};

typedef GamePlugin* (__cdecl* TKPROC)();
void PluginManager::Load(const string& name)
{
  HINSTANCE hinstLib;
  TKPROC ProcAdd;
  hinstLib = LoadLibrary(name.c_str());

  if (hinstLib != NULL)
  {
    m_moduleHandle = (void*)hinstLib;
    ProcAdd = (TKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "GetInstance");

    if (NULL != ProcAdd)
    {
      m_plugin = (ProcAdd)();
      m_plugin->Init();
    }
  }
}

void PluginManager::Unload()
{
  if (m_plugin)
  {
    m_plugin->Destroy();
    delete m_plugin;
  }

  if (m_moduleHandle)
  {
    FreeLibrary((HINSTANCE)m_moduleHandle);
    m_moduleHandle = nullptr;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
  PluginManager* pm = new PluginManager();
  pm->Load("plugin.dll");
  pm->Unload();
  delete pm;
  return 0;
}
```

Plugin interface:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _WIN32
#    ifdef TK_EXPORTS
#        define TK_GAME_API __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
#        define TK_GAME_API __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#elif
#    define TK_GAME_API
#endif

struct GamePlugin
{
  virtual void Init() = 0;
  virtual void Destroy() = 0;
  virtual void Frame() = 0;
};
```

DLL side:

```
#define TK_EXPORTS
#include "Plugin.h"
#include <vector>

class Game : public GamePlugin
{
public:
  void Init() {}
  void Destroy() {}
  void Frame() {}

  std::vector<int> point;
};

extern "C" TK_GAME_API GamePlugin * __stdcall GetInstance()
{
  return new Game();
}
```

Exactly the same, if we remove the `std::vector<int> point`, there is no leak.

Comment: Your assumption is not correct, FreeLibrary will not result in a call to delete Game;
You have to provide an explicit function, the opposite to GetInstance that will delete the game instance. And be careful the number of GetInstance calls match the number of DeleteInstance calls, they should be reference counted

Comment: Do you really want `GetInstance()` to return a new object every time it is called? If the caller doesn't keep track of and delete the instance you have a leak. If you're trying to implement a singleton then what you have is incorrect.

Comment: @PKramer When the instance is created, I store it in m_plugin and destroy it in PluginManager::unload

Comment: @RetiredNinja I call getinstance, store the object, delete the object at proper times. Name is leading to confusion, getinstance is called only once and its guaranteed by the process. The only reason that causes the leak is the std::vector class and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you sure that the instance pointer is `delete`-ed ? You didn't show that in your code.

Comment: @VainMan PluginManager::Unload -> SafeDel(m_plugin) this code deletes it. I can verify that in the debugger. It's long been in use.

Comment: @Cihan Then show that with code, eg. what exactly SafeDel does. Or consider to provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VainMan `#define SafeDel(ptr) { delete ptr; ptr = nullptr; }; `
If I remove the std::vector point, it does not complain about memory leaks, and I can allocate and free whitin the plugin safely. Std containers are not releasing the allocated memory. [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/memory-leaks-when-using-stl-container-classes-implemented-gnu-c-library) This might be a similar case. For the minimal-case, I am on it.

Comment: It's not leaked. It is re-usable for later allocations. If you don't need this feature(which usually has better performance) and really want to suppress that report from your checker, you can implement a custom-defined allocator that always calls malloc and free or `malloc_alloc` if available.

Comment: @VainMan I was thinking it to be something like this ... So upsetting than, how can one be sure that the leak report is true or false ...

Comment: Can we see a [mcve], please? Make sure it's complete and minimal.

Comment: @IInspectable I have updated the question. At the bottom, I have added the reproducable case. I am using visual studio 2019 and a 64 bit configuration.

Comment: By the way, I have used memory snapshot on the minimal case. Visual studio reports 3 created object up until `pm->Unload` plugin.ddl!Game, plugin.dll!std::_Container_proxy, process.exe!PluginManger and after the unload code executed, it clears all the mentionend memory. That is, all the allocated memory gets freed. However still it reports the std::vector as if its a leak. It seemed to me as a visual studio bug.

Comment: Please show a **minimal** test case. Remove all the C++ abstractions that merely make the code harder to read, but don't add anything. This should be illustrated using a C API, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the minimal case, I am creating the plugin instance in the dll however deleting it in the process / executable. Eventough the memory is being freed, it gets reported as leak because that memory allocated within the dll and not freed there. Wow what a hassle was that ....

There are better ways of doing this, but in case some one lives the same problem, here is a quick fix.

Process:

```
void PluginManager::Unload()
{
  if (m_plugin)
  {
    m_plugin->Destroy();
    m_plugin = nullptr; // Clear the memory in where it is allocated.
  }

  if (m_moduleHandle)
  {
    FreeLibrary((HINSTANCE)m_moduleHandle);
    m_moduleHandle = nullptr;
  }
}
```

DLL:

```
void Destroy() { delete this; } // Now CRT Debug is happy. No false leak repots.
```